# Excel macro data masking by changing character ASCII

Tags: excel, macros, data-masking

I'm working on a data masking tools by adding the ASCII of the characters, however it will hit an error once it reached the maximum ASCII number.

Is there any way to prevent or ignore the adding of the ASCII number if it's already reaching the maximum ASCII number?

My excel Code

```
Sub DataMask()
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim intChar As Integer
Dim strCheckString As String
Dim strCheckChar As String
Dim intCheckChar As Integer
Dim strClean As String

For Each rngCell In Selection
    strCheckString = rngCell.Value
    strClean = ""
    intChar = 1
    If strCheckString <> "" Then
        For intChar = 1 To Len(strCheckString)
           strCheckChar = Mid(strCheckString, intChar, 1)
           intCheckChar = Asc(strCheckChar) + 68
           strClean = strClean & Chr(intCheckChar)
        Next intChar
        rngCell.Value = strClean
    End If
Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include a piece of code like this:-

```
       If intCheckChar <= 255 Then
            newCheckChar = Chr(intCheckChar)
       Else
            newCheckChar = strCheckChar
       End If
       strClean = strClean & newCheckChar
```

to replace

```
       strClean = strClean & Chr(intCheckChar)
```

so if the new character has a code more than 255 it just uses the old character.

This is the whole sub with a couple of debug statements:-

```
sub DataMask()
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim intChar As Integer
Dim strCheckString As String
Dim strCheckChar As String
Dim intCheckChar As Integer
Dim strClean As String
Dim newCheckChar As String


For Each rngCell In Selection
    strCheckString = rngCell.Value
    strClean = ""
    intChar = 1
    If strCheckString <> "" Then
        For intChar = 1 To Len(strCheckString)
           strCheckChar = Mid(strCheckString, intChar, 1)
           intCheckChar = Asc(strCheckChar) + 68
           ' New code
           If intCheckChar <= 255 Then
                newCheckChar = Chr(intCheckChar)
            Else
                newCheckChar = strCheckChar
            End If
           strClean = strClean & newCheckChar
           Debug.Print ("intChar=" & intChar)
           Debug.Print ("intCheckChar=" & intCheckChar)
           ' end of code
        Next intChar
        rngCell.Value = strClean
    End If
Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the piece of code. However a new glitch appears when running the code for a string of characters. It will replicate the cell value each time you run the macro.

Example
ÅÅÅ > ÷÷÷ > ÷÷÷÷÷÷

Comment: That is very strange, I can't see how it can add more characters than were in the original string. I'll put my whole code in the answer with a couple of debug statements to try.